# Not getting Response Body from resttemplate.exchange while getting from postman Spring Mvc

Tags: java, spring

I am new to Spring MVC, I am using below code to get response from another application.
4.3.20.RELEASE

```
ResponseEntity<OtdsOauthToken> response = restTemplate.exchange(builder.toUriString(), HttpMethod.POST, entity, OtdsOauthToken.class); // Getting response object body as null, header is coming and Status is 200
```

Response body through Code :

[image]

Response body through Postman :

[image]

Comment: Show the OtdsOauthToken class please.

Comment: Unserialization issue? attributes names in response doesn't match attributes names in `OtdsOauthToken` class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you haven't yet shown the `OtdsOauthToken` class, for now I can only guess. I think the problem may be because of you haven't set JSON-attribute names (with snack-case) for the fields or/and may be the class doesn't contain getters/setters.
So, the class must look like this:

```
public class OtdsOauthToken {
    @JsonProperty("access_token")
    private String accessToken;

    private LocalDateTime expiration;

    @JsonProperty("expires_in")
    private Long expiresIn;

    @JsonProperty("token_type")
    private TokenType tokenType;

    public String getAccessToken() {
        return accessToken;
    }

    public void setAccessToken(String accessToken) {
        this.accessToken = accessToken;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getExpiration() {
        return expiration;
    }

    public void setExpiration(LocalDateTime expiration) {
        this.expiration = expiration;
    }

    public Long getExpiresIn() {
        return expiresIn;
    }

    public void setExpiresIn(Long expiresIn) {
        this.expiresIn = expiresIn;
    }

    public TokenType getTokenType() {
        return tokenType;
    }

    public void setTokenType(TokenType tokenType) {
        this.tokenType = tokenType;
    }
}
```

Also you can configure your `ObjectMapper` and omit setting of attribute names.

```
this.objectMapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategy.SNAKE_CASE);
```

In this case the class might look as simple POJO-class:

```
public class OtdsOauthToken {
    private String accessToken;
    private LocalDateTime expiration;
    private Long expiresIn;
    private TokenType tokenType;

    //getters ...
    //setters ...
}
```

Comment: Sorry for late reply got busy in production issues.

Answer (score 1):

From what I see in the debug code, your `OtdsOauthToken` class seems to have the field names as *camelCase*, while your response entity (in Postman) uses *snake_case*. That's why the `RestTemplate` doesn't know to set the values on your object.

The solution would be to annotate your fields with `@JsonProperty`, for example:

```
public class OtdsOauthToken {

    @JsonProperty("access_token")
    private String accessToken

    @JsonProperty("token_type")
    private String tokenType

    @JsonProperty("expires_in")
    private Integer expiresIn;

}
```

Comment: Yes that was the issue its working now. Thanks for help